# FileUpload, UpdatePanel and ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use a FileUpload control in a ModalPopupExtender in an UpdatePanel.

I have set a trigger for my Upload button, so that it does a full postback.

What happens is that after the full postback, all the ModalPopupExtenders that I have in the page show up one after the other at the bottom of my page, rah

I've tried using the AsyncFileUpload control, but have not been able to get the UploadEvent to fire, have tried everything I could find in Google.  Decided to stick with the FileUpload control.

```
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPEBannerImage" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnBannerImage" PopupControlID="pnlBannerImage" Y="200">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBannerImage" runat="server" Width="530px" >
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
   <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="btn-UploadFile.png"
                        ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: My issue with the AsyncFileUpload is that I cannot get the OnUploadComplete event to fire. I have set enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag in my master page

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, button that fires off the file download works outside of my modalPopupExtender/Updatepanel. But once inside it doesn't work, has something to do with it already executing an asynchronous callback when you try to do the response and apparently that can't happen. Don't know how to work around it though.